# Writing namespace extensions with Windows 7 integration

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shell-extensions

I'm new to the topic shell extensions and I'm looking for resources about namespace extensions. I would like to write a namespace extension which supports SFTP with all options to browse like FTP in the explorer.

I read the examples [1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/TipsInNSE_SubFld.aspx), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/NSExtAddDelFld.aspx) of zengxi from codeproject, but they don't compile right and seems to be old. I think that there were also many changes like the folder selection in the address bar.

Can somebody provide me some resources in the right direction or some working examples?

**UPDATE:**
It is important that the source is free. This is a non-profit project.

At the moment I found a good source on the MSDN called [Explorer Data Provider Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940360.aspx). This is up to date and provides some aliases `Explorer Data Provider` and `Shell Data Source`. What is yet missing is drop & drag support and a glue for supporting protocol links.

For future usage it would be great to find a way to associate a file extension with that `shell data source` like zip files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drag&Drop, [this series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/tags/what+a+drag/) are a great point to start. After I understood that the files must have the flag can copy, can move, etc. I had almost the solution. The magic was to add one line in `GetAttributesOf`:

```
*rgfInOut |= SFGAO_CANCOPY|SFGAO_CANMOVE;
```

Also I had to publish the `IDataObject` in `GetUIObjectOf` like this:

```
if(riid == IID_IDataObject) {
    PWSTR pszName;
    hr = _GetName(apidl[0], &pszName);
    hr = SHCreateDataObject(m_pidl, cidl, apidl,
                            new CFileDataObject(pszName), riid, ppv);
} else if(riid == IID_IDropTarget) {
    // TODO publish
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

That's all.

By the way what is the best practice for allocating `CFileDataObject` here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full example of creating a namespace to mapping real files on Flickr.
However, only source codes available. No tutorial.
Hope it helps....
http://www.viksoe.dk/code/flickrdrive.htm

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [EZNamespaceExtensionsMFC](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensionsmfc.htm) library which makes it very easy to develop namespace extensions. Check out its FileBrowser and RegBrowser samples which you can use a starting point.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of EZNamespaceExtensionsMFC

Comment: I saw your product. It looks exactly like I'm looking for, but I cannot buy a licence. This is at the moment a non-profit project idea, also I want to learn how the Namespace Extensions work.