# How can I add a folder like Dropbox and OneDrive do in windows 10 programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have been trying to add a dropbox like folder in the windows explorer.
But I am asking this question to check if there are already any tools, extensions or libraries to do that.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **dropbox like folder**? Do you mean `syncing`? or `shortcut in favorites`? or `icon in system tray`?

Comment: I edited the question just to make it clearer!

Comment: What do you mean? Dropbox and OneDrive do *not* add folders. Are you asking about shell and namespace extensions? They are available since Windows 2000 (probably earlier). Creating them using .NET is *not* supported because you'd have to host .NET in Windows Explorer itself. Even the Windows 7 Samples that showed how to do this were pulled from MSDN

Comment: How can I implement this? I am new to this stuff and I needed this in my application

Comment: You can't do this with .NET. You'll have to use C++. These things are called [Shell namespace extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521656(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438066/writing-namespace-extensions-with-windows-7-integration) points to some usefull samples like the [Explorer Data Provider Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940360.aspx) and includes modifications needed to enable Drag&Drop